# Is there a better way to define __get without using variable variables or an array for all member variables?

Tags: php

I'm making a BaseModel class and want to use magic methods __set and __get instead of defining setters and getters for every single property.

I'm currently using variable variables because I couldn't find another way by googling it. Are variable variables considered bad practice or am I fretting over nothing?

```
abstract class BaseModel implements \ArrayAccess {

/**
 * Don't allow these member variables to be written by __set
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $noSet = array();

/**
 * Don't allow these member variables to be retrieved by __get
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $noGet = array();

public function offsetExists( $offset )
{
    return property_exists($this, $offset);
}
public function offsetGet( $offset )
{
    return $this->__get($offset);
}
public function offsetSet( $offset , $value )
{
    return $this->__set($offset, $value);
}
public function offsetUnset( $offset )
{
    unset($this->$offset);
}

public function __get($member)
{
    if( $member == 'noSet' || $member == 'noGet')
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException ("Tried to access a forbidden property", 1);
    }

    if( ! property_exists($this, $member))
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException ("Tried to access a non-existent property", 1);
    }

    if( in_array($member, $this->noGet))
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException ("Tried to access a forbidden property", 1);
    }

    return $this->$member;
}

public function __set($member, $value)
{
    if( $member == 'noSet' || $member == 'noGet')
    {
        throw new \DomainException ("Tried write to a non-writable property.", 1);
    }

    if( ! property_exists($this, $member))
    {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException ("Tried to access a non-existent property", 1);
    }

    if( in_array($member, $this->noSet))
    {
        throw new \DomainException ("Tried write to a non-writable property.", 1);
    }

    return $this->$member = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems you think that `protected` keyword makes a property unable to be set/get using magic methods.  This is not the case.  This just makes it to where you can't directly access/modify these properties from outside the scope of the class (i.e. you can't do something like `$object->foo = 'bar'`)

Second, you seem to have misunderstanding of magic methods.  What they in fact do is to enforce behavior when a user tries to directly access/modify a property.  So in my example, if a user tries to do:

```
$object->foo = 'bar';
```

This is actually calls the `__set()` method and is equivalent to:

```
$object->__set('foo', 'bar');
```

So a typical class implementation using get/set magic methods might look like this:

```
class some_class {
    protected $foo;
    protected $foo2;
    public $pub;
    public function __construct() {
        // maybe do something here
    }
    public function __get($prop) {
        if(!property_exists($this, $prop) {
            throw new Exception('Tried to get unknown property ' . $prop);
        } else {
            return $this->{$prop};
        }
    }
    public function __set($prop, $value) {
        if(!property_exists($this, $prop) {
            throw new Exception('Tried to set unknown property ' . $prop);
        } else {
            $this->{$prop} = $value;
            return true; // or whatever you want to return
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would be as follows:

```
$object = new some_class();
$object->foo = 'bar'; // sets 'bar'
echo $object->foo; // echo 'bar;
var_dump($object->foo2); // null
$object->pub = 'something'; // does not call __set() as this property is available from global scope
echo $object->pub; // echo 'something' does not call __get() as this property is available from global scope
$object->no_prop; // throws Exception from __get() as property does not exist
```

It would seem to be odd usage to try to actually call `__get()` or `__set()` from within the class.

Check out the PHP documentation on object overloading for more information:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: `offsetExists`, and the other `offset*` methods are part of the [ArrayAccess interface](http://www.php.net/arrayaccess).

Comment: @zzzzBov I didn't notice the `implements` declaration earlier. Removed comment about that method.

Answer (score -1):

Variable variables are indeed the way to go.

Comment: PS: Check out __call. We got rid of so much cruft in our models :)